# How to create monthly histogram from yearly data?

Tags: pandas, plotly, histogram

I have created a random dataframe with hourly data for the whole year. So there are 8760 values total. This is how the data frame look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': pd.date_range('01-01-2022 00:00', '31-12-2022 23:00', freq='1H'),
        'LMP': np.random.randint(10, 100, 8760)
    }).set_index('Date')
```

I then group the `LMP` column by monthly format using the index column `Date`.

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month
df2 = df.groupby('month')['LMP'].apply(list)
print(df2)
```

which will look like:

```
month
1     [41, 98, 49, 78, 73, 49, 44, 33, 60, 29, 71, 1...
2     [93, 29, 70, 74, 15, 97, 10, 46, 59, 63, 52, 8...
3     [11, 36, 24, 54, 17, 65, 74, 63, 19, 36, 64, 8...
4     [86, 69, 27, 72, 48, 11, 61, 38, 80, 59, 74, 2...
5     [84, 48, 76, 51, 74, 60, 79, 46, 78, 50, 69, 3...
6     [24, 50, 14, 31, 35, 70, 92, 47, 66, 95, 67, 6...
7     [13, 69, 82, 15, 45, 98, 41, 72, 89, 40, 80, 5...
8     [42, 43, 86, 87, 24, 63, 52, 71, 62, 78, 35, 2...
9     [27, 75, 33, 74, 57, 59, 72, 68, 14, 80, 61, 8...
10    [17, 87, 83, 70, 90, 30, 32, 60, 99, 13, 88, 5...
11    [94, 11, 97, 69, 18, 75, 44, 97, 30, 21, 90, 2...
12    [54, 56, 85, 99, 37, 41, 76, 31, 49, 54, 35, 2...
Name: LMP, dtype: object
```

I want to create the histogram using plotly library and the x-axis should be catograized based on months.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=df2.index,y=df2.values, name="LMP"))
fig.show()
```

output is:
[image]

The expected output should look like this:
[image]

Comment: But your x-axis is intervals not numbers as in the column "Date".

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand the doubt

Comment: The expected output is a binned bar graph, right? Therefore, we need to perform binning as a preprocessing step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to make it as similar as possible to the desired output by using `go.bar` but first you change the dataframe a little:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': pd.date_range('01-01-2022 00:00', '31-12-2022 23:00', freq='1H'),
        'LMP': np.random.randint(0, 100, 8760)
    }).set_index('Date')

df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).month

start,end,step = (0,100,20)
labels = []
bins = []
for i in range(start,end+1,step):
    bins.append(i)
    if i != end:
        labels.append(str(i)+" - "+str(i+20))

df['range'] = pd.cut(df["LMP"], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df_new = df.groupby(["month","range"]).count().reset_index()
```

[image]

**Then add this code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for i in df_new["month"].unique():
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x = [df_new.loc[df_new["month"]==i,"month"],df_new.loc[df_new["month"]==i,"range"]],
        y = df_new.loc[df_new["month"]==i,"LMP"],
        name=str(i),
    ))


fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{y}', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', width=1200)
fig.show()
```

**The output will be:**
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the efforts and it is almost close to the expected output but the histogram should be something like : month and range column should be on the x axis and LMP should be on the y axis

Comment: I created the expected output graph using excel pivot table in which month and LMP are in the rows and count of LMP are in values.  Then create the Histogram from it.

Comment: we can create a pivot table in pandas also and I am almost there but I couldn't figure out the way to calculate the number of counts per value.

Comment: table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='LMP', index=['month', 'LMP'], columns=['LMP'], aggfunc='count')

Comment: this will give the desired x axis but the dataframe is empty and I don't know the reason

Comment: I can create the month and range columns in the same row but it will be too small and the labels of ranges will be overlapped

Comment: using px.histogram makes it easier to plot rather than manipulating your dataframe a lot to plot.

Comment: Yeah but I shared the expected output picture. That's how it should be other it won't make sense for me. Can you please tell me the reason why the dataframe is empty when I tried to create the Pivot table from it

Comment: Could you please change the value of `facet_col_wrap` to 12 instead of 4 to so how it looks like all months in a row. Because currently I am using my mobile :).

Comment: Yeah it is much more acceptable

Comment: Let me come back home after an hour and I will try to make it as the desired output (round 2) :)

Comment: There is one simpler method that will automatically create the data that I need to create the histogram df2 = df.groupby(['month','LMP'])['LMP'].count()

Comment: @Vesper, you should group by range after month instead of LMP because it is your x-axis has range values in each month. You can compare the output of your command with the output of my dataframe.